Implement Spring Authorization Server with 2 custom identity providers
I want to create a custom implementation of Spring Authorization Server with 2 custom federation providers:

First provider to authenticate clients with AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE for React web clients with login page. Used to get users from Keycloak.
Second provider for devices only with API access for devices - AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS. User credentials will fe fetched again from a second Cognito provider using API call.

Spring Security configuration:
    @Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);

        http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
                .tokenEndpoint(tokenEndpoint ->
                {
                    tokenEndpoint.accessTokenRequestConverter(new ThirdPartyPreAuthenticationConverter());
                    tokenEndpoint.authenticationProvider(
                            new ApikeyAuthenticationProvider(
                                    jwtGenerator(jwkSource()),
                                    oAuth2BasicTokenClaimsProvider,
                                    apikeyRegisteredClientRepository(passwordEncoder()),
                                    passwordEncoder(),
                                    tokenGenerator));
                    tokenEndpoint.authenticationProvider(
                            new UsersAuthenticationProvider(
                                    jwtGenerator(jwkSource()),
                                    pegasusClient,
                                    usersRegisteredClientRepository(passwordEncoder()),
                                    passwordEncoder(),
                                    tokenGenerator));
                    tokenEndpoint.accessTokenResponseHandler(new DispatchGeneratedTokenHandler());
                });

        http.oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2ResourceServer ->
                oauth2ResourceServer.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults())
        );

        // @formatter:on
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository apikeyRegisteredClientRepository(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        RegisteredClient tokenExchangeClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .clientId(clientId)
                .clientSecret(passwordEncoder.encode(clientSecret))
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
                .scope("internal.read")
                .scope("internal.write")
                .build();
        InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository = new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(tokenExchangeClient);
        registeredClientRepository.save(tokenExchangeClient);

        return registeredClientRepository;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository usersRegisteredClientRepository(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        RegisteredClient tokenExchangeClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .clientId(clientId)
                .clientSecret(passwordEncoder.encode(clientSecret))
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
                .scope("internal.read")
                .scope("internal.write")
                .redirectUri("http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/my-client") // Add at least one redirect URI
                .redirectUri("http://localhost:8080/authorized") // Another example URI
                .build();
        InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository = new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(tokenExchangeClient);
        registeredClientRepository.save(tokenExchangeClient);

        return registeredClientRepository;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    @Bean
    public JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource() {
        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
        KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
        RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
        RSAKey rsaKey = new RSAKey.Builder(publicKey)
                .privateKey(privateKey)
                .keyID(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .build();
        JWKSet jwkSet = new JWKSet(rsaKey);
        return (jwkSelector, securityContext) -> jwkSelector.select(jwkSet);
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder(JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource) {
        return OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.jwtDecoder(jwkSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtEncoder jwtGenerator(JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource) {
        return new NimbusJwtEncoder(jwkSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthorizationServerSettings authorizationServerSettings() {
        return AuthorizationServerSettings.builder().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider apikeyAuthenticationProvider() {
        return new ApikeyAuthenticationProvider(
                jwtGenerator(jwkSource()),
                oAuth2BasicTokenClaimsProvider,
                apikeyRegisteredClientRepository(passwordEncoder()),
                passwordEncoder(),
                tokenGenerator);
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public AuthenticationProvider usersAuthenticationProvider() {
        return new UsersAuthenticationProvider(
                jwtGenerator(jwkSource()),                    usersRegisteredClientRepository(passwordEncoder()),
                passwordEncoder(),
                tokenGenerator);
    }

User Provider:
public class UsersAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
    ....

    public UsersAuthenticationProvider(...) {
        .........
    }

    @Override
    public OAuth2AccessTokenAuthenticationToken authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        OAuth2ThirdPartyClientCredentialsAuthenticationToken token =
                (OAuth2ThirdPartyClientCredentialsAuthenticationToken) authentication;

        RegisteredClient registeredClient =
                registeredClientRepository.findByClientId(token.getClientId());
        if(registeredClient == null){
            throw new OAuth2AuthenticationException(OAuth2ErrorCodes.INVALID_CLIENT);
        }
        if(!encoder.matches(token.getClientSecret(), registeredClient.getClientSecret())) {
            throw new OAuth2AuthenticationException(OAuth2ErrorCodes.UNAUTHORIZED_CLIENT);
        }

        Map<String, Object> claims = null; // !!! TEMPORARY disabled
this.jwtEncoder.encode(JwtEncoderParameters.from(jwsHeaderBuilder.build(), claimsBuilder.build()));
        OAuth2AccessToken jwt = tokenGenerator.generateToken(claims);
        return new OAuth2AccessTokenAuthenticationToken(
                registeredClient,
                authentication,
                jwt);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return OAuth2ThirdPartyClientCredentialsAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);
    }
}

Second provider:
@Primary
public class ApikeyAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
    ...........

    public ApikeyAuthenticationProvider(........) {
        ..........
    }

    @Override
    public OAuth2AccessTokenAuthenticationToken authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        OAuth2ThirdPartyClientCredentialsAuthenticationToken token =
                (OAuth2ThirdPartyClientCredentialsAuthenticationToken) authentication;

        RegisteredClient registeredClient =
                registeredClientRepository.findByClientId(token.getClientId());
        if(registeredClient == null){
            throw new OAuth2AuthenticationException(OAuth2ErrorCodes.INVALID_CLIENT);
        }
        if(!encoder.matches(token.getClientSecret(), registeredClient.getClientSecret())) {
            throw new OAuth2AuthenticationException(OAuth2ErrorCodes.UNAUTHORIZED_CLIENT);
        }

        Map<String, Object> claims =
                apikeyAuthenticationProviderClient.getClaims(......);

        OAuth2AccessToken jwt = tokenGenerator.generateToken(claims);
        return new OAuth2AccessTokenAuthenticationToken(
                registeredClient,
                authentication,
                jwt);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return OAuth2ThirdPartyClientCredentialsAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);
    }
}

This setup is not working. Do you know what is the proper way to implement it?

To those of you that will look further into this: There is code in the question from this sample: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/tree/main/samples/demo-authorizationserver

@RoarS. If you have some knowledge in this area can you share is it a god practice to have one authenticationProvider class for users and a second for devices?

Looks ok, but can you show me code example with with 2 identity provides - one with AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE and one with AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS? If it's not possible can you show me example that you can implement?

Peter: Let's wipe this conversation for now in order to keep your issue neat and clean.
